# Criando aplicação player de música com JLayer

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Estou tentando criar uma aplicação Java que receba uma música através de `JFileChooser` e adicione essa música em uma lista (`ArrayList<File>`).

Porém ao acessar o arquivo `array.getindex(0).getPath()`, o sistema lança um `NullPointerException`.

Aqui está o código:

```
package br.lp2.view;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;

import br.lp2.player.*;
import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;
import javazoom.jl.player.advanced.AdvancedPlayer;
import br.lp2.main.*;

@SuppressWarnings({ "serial", "unused" })
public class GUI extends JFrame {


    JFileChooser jfile;
    Component parent = null;
    //private Player ply;


    // Dimensoes da tela principal
    private int ALTURA = 300;
    private int LARGURA = 500;

    //Player
    File p1Player;
    ArrayList<File> arrayMusic = new ArrayList<File>();
    private Player pl = null;

    // Janela de cadastro de usuario
    private CadastroUsuario cadastroUsuario = new CadastroUsuario();

    // Menu bar
    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    // Menus
    private JMenu menuMusicas = new JMenu("Musicas");
    private JMenu menuPlaylists = new JMenu("Playlists");
    private JMenu menuUsuarios = new JMenu("Usuarios");
    // Menu items
    private JMenuItem adicionarMusica = new JMenuItem("Adicionar musica");
    private JMenuItem removerMusica = new JMenuItem("Remover musica");
    private JMenuItem verMusicas = new JMenuItem("Ver lista de musicas");
    private JMenuItem verPlaylists = new JMenuItem("Ver playlists");    
    private JMenuItem criarPlaylist = new JMenuItem("Criar playlist");
    private JMenuItem removerPlaylist = new JMenuItem("Remover playlist");
    private JMenuItem verUsuarios = new JMenuItem("Ver lista de usuarios");
    private JMenuItem adicionarUsuario = new JMenuItem("Cadastrar        usuarios");
    private JMenuItem removerUsuario = new JMenuItem("Remover usuario");

    // Botoes
    private JButton play = new JButton("Play");
    private JButton pause = new JButton("Pause");
    private JButton proximaMusica = new JButton(">>");
    private JButton anteriorMusica = new JButton("<<");

    public GUI() {
        jfile = new JFileChooser();

        // Configuracoes padrao
        setTitle("Player de musica");
        setSize(LARGURA, ALTURA);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Adicionando menu
        menuBar.add(menuMusicas);
        menuBar.add(menuPlaylists);
        menuBar.add(menuUsuarios);
        // Adicionando itens aos menus
        menuMusicas.add(verMusicas);
        menuMusicas.add(adicionarMusica);
        menuMusicas.add(removerMusica);
        menuPlaylists.add(verPlaylists);
        menuPlaylists.add(criarPlaylist);
        menuPlaylists.add(removerPlaylist);
        menuUsuarios.add(verUsuarios);
        menuUsuarios.add(adicionarUsuario);
        menuUsuarios.add(removerUsuario);
        // Setando menubar
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        // Adicionando botoes
        add(play);
         add(pause);
        add(proximaMusica);
        add(anteriorMusica);
        // Setando posicao dos botoes
        play.setBounds(70, ALTURA - 90, 100, 30);
        pause.setBounds(180, ALTURA - 90, 100, 30);
        proximaMusica.setBounds(290, ALTURA - 90, 50, 30);
    anteriorMusica.setBounds(10, ALTURA - 90, 50, 30);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pause.setEnabled(false);
    // Login inicial
    // Login login = new Login();       

    // Eventos
    adicionarMusica.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            jfile.showOpenDialog(parent);
            p1Player = jfile.getSelectedFile(); 
            try{
                arrayMusic.add(p1Player);
            }catch (NullPointerException ex){
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                System.out.println(ex.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
    });

    play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pause.setEnabled(true);
            play.setEnabled(false);
            Music msc = new Music();
            msc.start();

        }
    });         
    pause.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            play.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });

    adicionarUsuario.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cadastroUsuario.setVisible(true);               
        }
    });
}

/*class Music extends Thread implements Runnable{
    public void run(File file_t) throws FileNotFoundException{
        System.out.println("chegou aqui");
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file_t);
        PlayerFile ply = new PlayerFile(file_t);
        Thread playing = new Thread((Runnable) ply);
        playing.run();
    }
}*/
class Music extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        try {
        System.out.println("chegou aqui222");
        //System.out.println("CAMINHO " + arrayMusic.get(0).getPath());
        InputStream teste = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("C:/Users/pedrohbcavalcante/Downloads/ateste.mp3");
        //System.out.println("GETPATH() " + file.getPath() + " GETABSOLUTPATH() "+ file.getAbsolutePath());
            pl = new Player(teste);
            pl.play();
        } catch (JavaLayerException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Me resultou no seguinte stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException: in
    at javazoom.jl.decoder.Bitstream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javazoom.jl.player.Player.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javazoom.jl.player.Player.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at br.lp2.view.GUI$Music.run(GUI.java:174)
```

Comment: Olá PEdro, você poderia editar a pergunta e incluir o stack trace? Também seria interessante simplificar o seu exemplo (veja que outros usuários não possuem classes como `CadastroUsuario`, ficando difícil rodar o seu codigo para tentar reproduzir o problema).

Comment: Olá Anthony, fiz uma alteração para chamar a classe Music atraves do .start() e me resultou nos stack que está no edit. Se tratando da classe CadastroUsuario, ela é só outra parte do projeto onde é mais ligada ao view. é só algo de comentar, como já está aí. Obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `NullPointerException` está vindo do construtor da classe `Bitstream`. Ou seja, [daqui](https://github.com/libgdx/jlayer-gdx/blob/master/src/javazoom/jl/decoder/Bitstream.java#L130).

De acordo com o código-fonte da classe `BitStream`:

> ```
>     public Bitstream (InputStream in) {
>         if (in == null) throw new NullPointerException("in");
> ```

Ou seja, o parâmetro `in` passado ao construtor era nulo.

Subindo no stacktrace temos o construtor da classe `Player`. Essa classe não existe mais na versão mais atual do *JLayer-gdx*. Entretanto, ao olhar na versão anterior, essa classe existia. Olhando [no código do commit onde foi removido](https://github.com/libgdx/jlayer-gdx/commit/18d1e14128fefaf2f5e14e6daaee6bff6516a3c0), temos isso:

```
public Player(InputStream stream) throws JavaLayerException
{
    this(stream, null); 
}

public Player(InputStream stream, AudioDevice device) throws JavaLayerException
{
    bitstream = new Bitstream(stream);
```

Ou seja, o parâmetro `stream` era nulo.

Subindo mais no stacktrace, chegamos nessa linha do seu código:

```
            pl = new Player(teste);
```

Ou seja, `teste` era nulo. Essa variável tem seu valor atribuído aqui:

```
        InputStream teste = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("C:/Users/pedrohbcavalcante/Downloads/ateste.mp3");
```

E isso está errado! O `getResourceAsStream(...)` retorna nulo quando não encontra o recurso procurado.

Por que ele não achou o recurso? Porque o método `getResourceAsStream(...)` serve para procurar recursos dentro do arquivo JAR (ou WAR ou EAR) que contém a sua aplicação. Porém, este não é o seu caso, o recurso não está dentro do JAR, e sim diretamente no sistema de arquivos.

A solução seria usar algo assim:

```
        InputStream teste = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/pedrohbcavalcante/Downloads/ateste.mp3");
```

Ao usar o `FileInputStream`, o recurso será procurado dentro do sistema de arquivos. O compilador vai reclamar que faltaria um `IOException`, que é o que é lançado se ocrrer um erro ao tentar localizar o arquivo (possivelmente `FileNotFoundException`, que é subclasse de `IOException`, para o caso de o arquivo não existir). Assim sendo, coloque mais um `catch` para o `IOException`.